# CSS display error - Safari is adding break in navigation bar

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

The navigation bar is being displayed correctly using Firefox and Chrome, but when opening the website with Safari on an iPad or Mac(Safari) the navigation bar is displayed wrong. (There is being added a break after a few links)

This is the site: http://t1p.de/safari
You can find the nav bar at the top right corner.

What can I do to get the navigation bar diplayed correct again?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe add some prints instead of the link, so we won't have to open the site on safari to help you

Comment: Adding some info on your components would be useful too, are you using any CSS library?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using Bootstrap CSS 3 and had to add some width to fix the line break on Safari:

```
.nav.navbar-nav{
  width: 70%;
}
```